# Query of Oracle database using RJDBC

Tags: sql, r, oracle, rjdbc

Using RJDBC to connect to a server, which hosts an oracle (11.2g) database, I can use DBI::dbGetQuery() to get results from queries. RJDBC::dbGetTables() and DBI::dbListTables() both work.

I cannot, however, use the dplyr::tbl() to work with the db-tables as if they were in-memory objects, using dplyr verbs for example. I was able to do in my former job and liked it very much :-)

```
tbl(con, in_schema("abc","TABLE_NAME"))
```

results in:

```
Error in `dplyr::db_query_fields()`:
! Can't query fields.
Caused by error in `dbSendQuery()`:
! Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

  Statement: SELECT *
FROM "abc"."TABLE_NAME" AS "q01"
WHERE (0 = 1)
```

I have already tried the following from posit (https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/databases/oracle/):

```
sql_translation.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_translation.Oracle
sql_select.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_query_select.Oracle
sql_subquery.JDBCConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_query_wrap.Oracle
```

but now

```
tbl(con, in_schema("abc","TABLE_NAME"))
```

results in:

```
Error in `collect()`:
! Failed to collect lazy table.
Caused by error in `dbSendQuery()`:
! Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

  Statement: SELECT *
FROM ("abc"."TABLE_NAME") 
FETCH FIRST 11 ROWS ONLY
```

Since I have the feeling that our oracle version doesn't like "FETCH FIRST", I've changed the query being sent with this:

```
trace(dbplyr:::sql_query_select.Oracle, edit=TRUE)
```

replacing `"FETCH FIRST ", <limit>, "ONLY"` with `"WHERE ROWNUM <", <limit>"`. This returns a result! But: 1) R believes the first 10 rows to be all there is (and doesn't know the query was lazy) and 2) dyplr::filter doesn't work as it returns:

```
Error in `collect()`:
! Failed to collect lazy table.
Caused by error in `dbSendQuery()`:
! Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

  Statement: SELECT *
FROM ("abc"."TABLE_NAME") 
WHERE ("variable" = x)
WHERE ROWNUM < 11
```

So how to achieve that dplyr verbs work and R perfoming lazy queries (and knowing about it)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "abc"."TABLE_NAME" AS "q01"
WHERE (0 = 1)
```

Is invalid as Oracle forbids you using the `AS` for a table alias; if you get R to generate SQL with the correct dialect so that it does not use `AS` before table aliases then it should work.

---

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ("abc"."TABLE_NAME") 
WHERE ("variable" = x)
WHERE ROWNUM < 11
```

Is invalid as you have two `WHERE` clauses; the second `WHERE` should be an `AND`.

> R believes the first 10 rows to be all there is

If you have hardcoded a static filter to a query that limits the output to `ROWNUM < 11` then you will only ever get 10 rows (and those rows will be the first 10 random rows that match the filter conditions, not 10 rows in a specific order). So, R is correct, that is all there is with a hardcoded filter of 10 rows.

If you want to paginate a query then you want (for example, fetching rows 101-110):

```sql
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3
FROM   (
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         column3,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT column1,
           column2,
           column3
    FROM   "abc"."TABLE_NAME"
    WHERE  "variable" = x
    ORDER BY something
  )
  WHERE  ROWNUM <= 110
)
WHERE rn > 100
```

*(Order first, then filter by the upper bound and use an inline view to materialise the row numbering and then filter by the lower bound using the materialised row number.)*

Comment: thanks for your answer! Running the code [...dbplyr:::sql_query_select.Oracle] changes the sql translation dbplyr does, so there is no more "AS". But our oracle database seems to decline "Fetch First", that's why I tried "ROWNUM". Unfortunately, I'm not skilled enough to change the sql translation of dbplyr into what you suggested.

Comment: I found that somebody before me had the same problem 8https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/658) and was able to fix it. Unfortunately I am not able to change the dbplyr function as this person did since dbplyr has even further progressed in the meantime.